# Error Cabeceira appears

Tags: errors

I am running the TEX file to get PDF , but I see the following error, how can I solve that?
[image: Cabeceira Error]
Many thanks for your time

Comment: Put a percent sign in front of `\usepackage{cabeceira}`. By the way, you should not post a screenshot of your errors, but copy them from the log file and post them in a code block.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te